# Agora token generation with cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, token, agora.io

i am trying to generate agora token for video call. I have deployed a cloud function for that but it is giving me the following error "the error I am getting is "the first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object."

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Agora = require("agora-access-token");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.tokenGeneration = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const appID = "appId";
  const appCertificate = "appCertificate";
  const uid = request.body.role == 0 ? 0 : 1;
  const role = request.body.role == 0 ? Agora.RtcRole.PUBLISHER : Agora.RtcRole.SUBSCRIBER;
  const channel = request.body.channelName;
  const expirationTimestamp = parseInt(request.body.expireTimestamp);

  const token = Agora.RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(appID, appCertificate, channel, uid, role, expirationTimestamp);
  response.send({ "token" : token });
});
```

And this is my payload:

{
'channelName': "amankachannel",
'uid': 0,
'role': 1,
'expireTimestamp': "3456783476547"
}

Answer (score 0):

first argument id agora AppID. Check you AppID is valid or not